# Ios to observe changes in soap response?

Tags: ios, soap

I am writing an app that when I send a soap request to the server I will receive a soap response that I will store some of its elements as an object's properties.

Are there any ways that I can keep observing changes of the response without manually shooting the same soap request continuously to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally sorted. I have found that I can http SUBSCRIBE to the server to receive http notification (http response with "notify" header and XML body) whenever there is any change to the song that I am playing.

I have then built a http server in my iPhone app (GCDWebServer) to enable the listening to the above http notifications. These notifications are considered as "request" instead of response from the server's perspective.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to query the server each time, you may try to integrate a websocket implementation, so you can listen a specific for any change events that will be sent by the server.

Comment: Thanks. I found an open sourced objective c class called SRWebSocket that I tried to initwithURLRequest using the soap request then watch for response through the delegate. However, there's not been any response.  Don't think I should request using the soap request right?  If not, what should I then do?

Comment: Do you have the control of the web server you are retrieving data? If you have, you have to implement the websocket also on that web server. If you don't have any control over it sorry but you can't use it. You only have what server gives you. It is a two-sided protocol.

Comment: I have no control on the server side.  Thanks, so this is not a solution in my case then.